# getImageData when clicking a dynamic button

Tags: javascript

I have created two dynamic buttons with javascript. I would like them to getImage1Data and getImage2Data respectfully from sample.js when I click on them. Since these buttons are created dynamically, I'm not certain how to go about doing this. I am providing the html code along with the sample.js file.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">


    .btn {
    font-family     : Arial;
    text-align      : center;
    width           : 100px;
    height          : 15px;
    background      : #ccc;
    border          : 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow      : 1px 1px 5px -1px #000;
    padding         : 10px;
    margin-bottom   : 10px;
    cursor          : pointer;
    }

    .btn:hover {
       text-decoration : underline;   
    }

    </style>

    </head>
    <body>


   <script language="javascript">
       var button = 'btn1,btn2'.split(',');
    for (var b in button) {
        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.id = button[b]; newElement.className = "btn";
        newElement.innerHTML = button[b];
       document.body.appendChild(newElement);
    }

   </script>

   </body>
   </html>

/***********************************/
/***********************************/

SAMPLE.js

    var  image2Src = null;  

    function getImage1Data(){     
       var  image1Src;     
       var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
       xhttp.open("Get", 'some Url', false);     
       xhttp.send(null);     
       image1Src = xmlhttp.responseText; //Assume src = 'myFirstImg.png',  
       200x200 px  
    }   


    function getImage2Data(){      

       var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     
       xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){         
          if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status ==  
    200)                    
             getSrc(xmlhttp.responseText);     
    }        

          xhttp.open("Get", 'some Url', true);         
          xhttp.send(null); 
    }  

    function getSrc(text){     
       image2Src = text; //Assume src = 'myLastImg.png', 10x10 px 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the buttons are created dynamically(ie after the for loop),you can assign an  onclick event to these button elements.

```
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = getImage1Data;
document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = getImage2Data;
```

When the button element with id btn1 is clicked,it will call the getImage1Data function and on clicking the button with id btn2,the function getImage2Data gets called.
Remember to include sample.js on your HTML page above your button creation code.